# Creating a 60 second timer with /title command in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to create a fairly long timer with

```
   /title @a actionbar §lGame starts in §a01:00
```

But I do not want to have to use 61 command blocks, but still want a second by second countdown *displayed constantly without any gaps*.

How would I do this only with command blocks in a compact fashion?

Answer (score 3):

You can store seconds and minutes in a scoreboard as if they were real players. The same is for any variables you want.

Also, you can use [`/titleraw`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/title) command because [raw JSON text format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raw_JSON_text_format) supports player's score embedding.

---

## Setup

Before building the mechanism itself, you should create a scoreboard where the variables will be stored:

`/scoreboard objectives add vars dummy`

Next, let's set initial values for the `minutes` and `seconds`:

`/scoreboard players set minutes vars 1`

`/scoreboard players set seconds vars 0`

## The mechanism

[image: The mechnanism]

[1] (formatted time printing): `titleraw @a actionbar {"rawtext": [{"text": "Remaining Time: 0"}, {"score": {"name": "minutes", "objective": "vars"}}, {"text": ":"}, {"score": {"name": "seconds", "objective": "vars"}}]}`

*NB:* if your timer is longer than 09:59, you should delete the zero at `"Remaining Time: 0"`.

[2] (`seconds` decrementing): `scoreboard players remove seconds vars 1`

[3] (test for `seconds` reached -1; in this way, it goes to [4] by comparator): `scoreboard players test seconds vars -1 -1`

[4] (setting `seconds` to 59): `scoreboard players set seconds vars 59`

[5] (`minutes` decrementing): `scoreboard players remove minutes vars 1`

[6] (test for `minutes` reached -1; in this way, it [blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Repeater#Signal_locking) the repeater clock): `scoreboard players test minutes vars -1 -1`

## Restarting the timer

To restart it, you need to set initial values for `minutes` and `seconds` as I said above and replace the comparator between [3] and [4] command blocks.